# Question about feature extractor in end-to-end OCR model

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, ocr

I'm reading this interesting paper [Towards Unconstrained End-to-End Text Spotting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.09231.pdf) and having a question about the feature extractor.

In section 3.1. Feature Extractor, the authors said they modified the **conv4_1** to have stride 1. But right after that they said they extract features from **the output of stage 3**. I do not understand why modifying stage 4 needed when they already stopped at stage 3. Can anyone please explain this to me? Thank you so much.